# How to find out per PowerShell Script if a Solution is activated and where it is activated

Tags: 2013, powershell, feature, script

i have a Solution with the name

```
My.Solutionname
```

as the result of it i have a WSP with the name

```
My.Solutionname.wsp
```

It includes one Site and one Web scoped Feature. I have a SharePoint 2013 Farm with the WebAplication

```
http://sp2013
```

I have deployed this solution and activated the features on several SiteCollections. But i dont know where eaxctly.

How can i find out per PS Script on which SiteCollections within the given WebApplication the web and the site scoped Features was activated?

Answer (score 0):

I found it and could successfully use  it under SP2013. This is what i have used:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | Where-Object { (Get-SPFeature "My.Solutionname_Feature" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Site $_.Url) -ne $null } | Select Url
```